# Make transparent object not layer up itself

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

I want to make object transparent, but the object itself should not be visible through itself. It's in an animation that rotates it, but at a certain angle I can see parts of the object through other parts of the object, which I don't want. So object should be transparent for everything in the scene, but this object. Below I pointed with red arrows those "whiter" pieces that are semitransparent white over semitransparent white which I don't want to get:

[image: Sample showing problem]

Currently it have 3 materials on it (front, back and sides) and transparency + backface culling is done like this:

[image: Transparency]
[image: Backface culling]

For rendering I'm using Cycles engine and Blender 2.73.1. Is there anything I could do to make that happen? I think it got something to do with geometry settings but I have no idea what to set and how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the transmission depth which is number of transparent points the ray has passed through, this is on the Light path node:

[image]

The result image

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To get a material with one transparency and completely clear for the backfaces. Add together the *Backfacing* output on the *Geometry* node, with the *Transmission Depth* in the *Light Path* node.
Use that composite as the mix factor between your color, and completely clear.
[image: cycles nodes]

This will not only make faces in the same mesh invisible, but any number of objects with this material will become a solid transparent mass.

Here I have three separate objects, no doubled up shading between any of them.
[image: example render]

Comment: That's a good answer as well, but I awarded Answered to first person who pointed me in right direction. As a programmer I used Greater Than math node and And math node to make it work (really hate 2 as a result of logical operation).

Comment: @Migol if you find a better answer to your question you can change your mind and accept a different one.

Comment: :) understandable. But when using the output to mix colors, a value higher then 1 is not a problem.