# Transparent character

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency

I was testing out different solutions I had found but for 2.8 how do u get a image textured character to be transparent like he's a ghost or a out of body experience kind of thing. It shows that the dude is there but he's invisible to everyone but the viewer.

It's like this[image]

You can clearly see Casper but u can also see through his body. Like the candles and the picture frame.

Comment: For those of us who have never seen  ghosts or had any out of body experiences, it would be better if you showed us an reference image of what you are trying to get. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You never seen cartoons? Like when sponge bob started entering people dreams or at the very least Casper the friendly ghost.

Comment: Try to show how is your character's material setup made, what you tried and didn't work. Also, it seems you're referring at 2.8, did 2.79 work, and how?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/make-transparent-object-not-layer-up-itself

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are referring to a material setup called HOLOGRAM

Try this material setup in the image
[image: HOLOGRAM material setup]

It will make your ghost blueish and transparent, and it will give a Fresnel effect which talks about the angle of view

Comment: I've corrected it

Comment: While this might be a solution, it is hard to understand why you decided to use all of the many options shown, or how to apply them in other circumstances. ( *Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.*)

Comment: Thx for the help. It didn't work for me maybe I don't know how to import the texture into but I know what to look for which is very helpful.